# Sharepoint Add-In fails to install in Sharepoint Root Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint, add-in, office-store

when I want to install my "Sharepoint Add-In" ( *.app ) to the
Root Site Collection ( https://[myroot].sharepoint.com ), it will not install, the App-Icon appears greyed-out.
There is no error message, the install just does not continue.

1. I uploaded the Add-In ( *.app ) to the Sharepoint Root "App-Catalog" Site
2. From the Root Site Collection, I go to "Add an App > From my organization" and select the Add-In
3. After selecting the App it tries to install but then nothing happenend.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not the SP Farm Account or Setup Account as you will not be able to install the add-in as a system account. Try to grant access to the catalog and root site to a particular user for the install and deployment.